# setting up a ColdFusion proxy for XMLHttpRequests

Tags: coldfusion, proxy, xmlhttprequest

Here's the scenario:

I'm setting up a site where I need to do cross-domain XMLHttpRequests, and the external feed is XML.

Because of some restrictions on the web server, I need the proxy to be written in ColdFusion. The URI that needs to be proxied is dynamic, but a set URI is good for now.

I've never written a single line in ColdFusion, so help is much appreciated.

_L

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to implement the Remote Proxy Pattern. There have been some tutorials and articles on this for ColdFusion.  The ColdSpring framework can help you create them, but using ColdSpring is not necessarily easy for someone new to ColdFusion.

These might be what you're looking for:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1501-Creating-A-Remote-AJAX-Proxy-In-Javascript-Without-ColdFusion-8-s-CFAjaxProxy.htm
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1564-Ask-Ben-Accessing-Cached-CFCs-With-AJAX-via-Remote-Proxies.htm
http://randolphlinmark.com/post.cfm/the-remote-proxy-pattern-and-coldfusion-1